# How can I create a Correlation Plot?

Tags: flutter, dart

I am creating a statistics app with flutter for a machine learning project. And I wanted to create a correlation plot. Something like this:

[image]

I am using this package for the other graphs but it doesn't have anything that nears this.

```
dependencies:
  charts_flutter: ^0.8.1
```

Is there a way on how can I achieve this? It can be something similar to this but it has to represent the same thing.

Comment: This looks extremely trivial to create yourself. Why do you not have a go at it?

Comment: @creativecreatorormaybenot I have tried using Scatter Plot from that library, but I don't know how to customize it so it has String values on both axis. I can't see another way on how to do it. Other kinds of charts don't seem to be adequate for it. So I really don't know where to start or with what.

Comment: I mean creating it yourself as in writing your own `RenderObject` or `CustomPainter`.

Comment: @creativecreatorormaybenot I haven't worked with them since I have only a few months in flutter and in mobile development also. But I'll give it a try. I hope they are not really advanced.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend starting with a `CustomPainter`.

It should just be a bit of maths to place the rectangles and the text on the Cartesian plane. You do not even need to calculate your opacities because your values seem to already range from `0` to `1` in magnitude. [The `CustomPainter` documentation](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/rendering/CustomPainter-class.html) also features a video explaining how to work with it, which should make getting into it even easier.